# How to set Multi Level Foreign Key field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that looks like this

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Level_0(models.Model):
    Kode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="")

class Level_1(models.Model):
    Kode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    Level_0= models.ForeignKey(Level_0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Level_2(models.Model):
    Kode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    Level_1 = models.ForeignKey(Level_1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Level_0 = ????????????

    # how do I create a connection to Level_0? a field that is automatically filled with Level_0?
```

What I want to have is a field in `Level_2` that automatically connects to `Level_0` through `Level_1`. How do I add that field in my `Level_2` model?

Comment: With Django you have access to Level_0 automatically. I don't remember exact syntax, but it should be similar to this: level_2_instance.Level_1.Level_0.

Comment: As @Valera Grishin said, as long as they are linked to each other, you can query between them using the `related_names`. By default, it is `object.orderset()` unless you specify a `related_name` attribute in the model field. I don't know the syntax, but this should work: `Level_2.Level_1.order_set.Level_0.order_set.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I just set the default!

```
class Level_2(models.Model):
    Kode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    Level_1 = models.ForeignKey(Level_1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # The answer!!
    Level_0 = models.ForeignKey(Level_0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It connects through `Level_1` and django automatically assign the value for you when you entry your data. So far this works for me.

---

this works if I use Django Admin, and Django automatically connects corrects it even if you fill `Level_0` with something else. It will rectify it to the correct value.